# C Sharp compilation error

Tags: c#

I am getting a error while compiling some C# code, It says:

> The Type or namespace name could not
>   be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or assembly reference?)

I cannot fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. Post the code you are getting the error from. We can't guess what code you misspelled. 2. Change the tags to something that reflects the problem

Comment: You're probably using a type or namespace that the compiler couldn't find. Have you checked whether you are missing a using directive or assembly reference? Its probably either one of those two things or a typo in the code (case sensitivity?).

Answer (score 4):

There are only a few usual causes to this.

1. You need to add a reference to the DLL that contains the namespace.
2. You may have forgotten to add the name space in the using clauses at the top.
3. You mis-spelt it
4. It was valid in an older version of the reference but has now moved / been renamed / superceeded.

Without code, or even the full error (eg what namespace/type cant be found) we cant offer help - if you arent sure, google the name space name / type it says is missing.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the DLL doesn't "contain the namespace"... it contains a type that is declared to belong to a namespace, but the namespace itself could span multiple assemblies.

Comment: True, was trying to keept it simplistic, but you're right, it is important to know its not a 1->1 thing